# Django:Pass extra_context to reset_password view and receive the extra_context in given template

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am trying to redirect the password reset view to another template from the url directly as:

```
url(r'^accounts/password/reset/', password_reset, {'template_name':'users/login.html', 'extra_context':{'reset':'1'}, 'post_reset_redirect':'/users/accounts/login'}, name='password_reset'),
```

I have passed a context I need to use in my template.

In my 'users/login.html' template, I tried using:

```
            console.log('{{reset}}');
```

But the console does not display anything.

Is something missing? Or I am accessing the context in a wrong way?

URL patterns:

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^accounts/login/', web_login, name='web_login'),
url(r'^accounts/password/reset/', password_reset, {'template_name':'users/login.html', 'extra_context':{'reset':'1'}, 'post_reset_redirect':'/users/accounts/login'}, name='password_reset'),
url(r'^signup/', web_signup, name='web_signup'),
url(r'^create_role/', create_role, name='create_role'),
url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    views.activate, name='activate'),]
```

Template: users/login.html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-thankyou" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-thankyou-tab">
    <h5 class="mb-3">
        Success!
    </h5>
    <p>
        We have sent you an email with reset instructions.
    </p>
    <p>
        If the email does not arrive soon, check your spam folder. It was sent from <strong>support@fieldsight.org</strong>.
    </p>
    <button type="button" id="btn-backtologin" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="la la-long-arrow-left"></i> Back to Login</button>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-reset" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-reset-tab">
    <h5 class="mb-3">
        Forgot your password?
    </h5>
    <p>
        Don't worry. Resetting your password is easy, just tell us the email address you registered with <strong>Fieldsight</strong>.
    </p>
    <form method="post" action="/users/accounts/password/reset/">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputResetEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputResetEmail" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-resetpassword"><i class="la la-send" ></i> Submit</button>
        <button type="button" id="btn-backtologinfromreset" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="la la-long-arrow-left"></i> Back to Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
if('{{reset}}'=='1'){
    $('#pills-reset').removeClass('active show');
    $('#pills-thankyou').tab('show');

    fn_login_eqheight();
    fn_login_vertically_center();
    }
console.log('{{reset}}');
```

I even tried using `{{ form.reset }}` but the result was empty.

In my HTML console:

```
if(''=='1'){
    $('#pills-reset').removeClass('active show');
    $('#pills-thankyou').tab('show');

    fn_login_eqheight();
    fn_login_vertically_center();
}
console.log('');
```

Comment: can you show how you passed context?

Comment: It's included in the url as 'extra_context'

Comment: better if you do `return render (request,'login.html',{'reset':'1'})` in view that way it will be dynamic not hardcoded like here

Comment: I am using the defualt django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset view because i just want to override the template and pass a data to that template.

Comment: Your URL pattern might not be being used, but we can’t tell unless you show your full URL config. If you are using a recent version of Django, you should use the class based view instead of `password_reset`.

Comment: The URL pattern is being used because it redirects to the required template and also if the stated URL was not being hit, it would redirect to registration/password_reset_done.html, but it is not doing so. I am using Django version 1.8.18.

Comment: Can you also provide more details on your template file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for some solutions, I came up with the idea that the `'post_reset_redirect':'/users/accounts/login'` in the url is redirects to my `web_login` view function.

Then I was able to catch the `extra_context` passed from the `password_reset` view in my `web_login` view using:

```
reset = request.GET.get('reset')
```

Then I passed this variable in my template after which the required functionality was achieved.
Thank you everyone for spending your time looking into this problem.

Answer (score 3):

In django 3 (not sure about v2), if you are using an html email template. The following will work to send in template variables. The following code is in urls.py

```
path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
    extra_email_context={'var': something},
    html_email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html')),
```

The addition of 'extra_email_context' is what sends in a dict of parameters to be forwarded to the template.